# Updating an object impacts an array, after I've pushed the obejct into the array?

Tags: arrays, cryptography

I'm writing code in JavaScript running on nodejs.

The intent is to capture a trading candles worth of data into an object, then push that object into an array, where I can store and reference multiple candle's worth of data.  I'm getting stuck on the simplest of first steps (not a pro).

My simplified code is below.  I've removed a lot just to make the example without adding more code than necessary.

```
var bitcoinCandleHistoryArray = [];

var candleObject = {
open: 0,
high: 0,
low: 0,
close: 0,
volume: 0
};


candleObject.open = 100;
candleObject.high = 100;
candleObject.low = 100;
candleObject.close = 100;
candleObject.volume = 10000;

bitcoinCandleHistoryArray.push(candleObject);

candleObject.open = 0;
candleObject.high = 0;
candleObject.low = 0;
candleObject.close = 0;
candleObject.volume = 0;

bitcoinCandleHistoryArray.push(candleObject);
```

Essentially, if I update my candleObject, then push the first candleObject values to the array, I get a an array with my first candle in it.  Then if I update my candle object, prior to pushing a second candle in, the array's first candle entry will update.....before I've pushed it....

So if I set candleObject.open = 0, then [bitcoinCandleHistoryArray[0].open also immediately becomes 0, without a push.

```
 


I was expecting the CandleObject's values to be independent of any values in my array.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was expecting the CandleObject's values to be independent of any values in my array.

They are not. After you push `candleObject` into the array, the variable `candleObject` still references the same object that is now also in the array (referenced by the array).

For the data to be independent, you need to create a new object for each element in the array.

You could either do so by inlining the creation of the objects like this:

```
var bitcoinCandleHistoryArray = [];

bitcoinCandleHistoryArray.push({
    open: 0,
    high: 0,
    low: 0,
    close: 0,
    volume: 0
});

bitcoinCandleHistoryArray.push({
    open: 100,
    high: 100,
    low: 100,
    close: 100,
    volume: 10000
});
```

Or, in case you want to stay closer to your original example, you can look into [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), which allows you do make a copy of `candleObject` that can then be pushed into the array.